# Index of critical points derivation

Tags: vector-spaces

I read in the textbook that the index of a critical point in vector field $v$ on curve $C$ is

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(C,v)&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\oint_Cd\theta=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\oint_Cd(arctan\dfrac{v_2}{v_1})\\
&\color{red}{=} \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C\dfrac{1}{1+(\frac{v_2}{v_1})^2}\cdot\dfrac{v_1dv_2-v_2dv_1}{v_1^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Can someone please explain how do we get the last step please? The textbook omits the explanation. Thanks.